# Quebrar linhas em uma lista vinda do banco

Tags: java, android, sql-server

Tenho este Dao que Faz Uma Pesquisa ao Banco de Dados Sql Server

```
    public String nomeTabela() {

        String nomeData = "";
        String nomeAlarme = "";
        String nomeRecebe = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "******.****.**:****";
        objConexao.db_name = "********";
        objConexao.db_userid = "****";
        objConexao.db_password = "*******";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);

        ArrayList list = null;
        if (conn == null) {


            nomeRecebe = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

        } else if (conn != null) try {


            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select TOP 100 Area,E3TimeStamp,Message from Alarmescelular Where AREA = ' Elevatória R7' order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
            ResultSet rs;


            rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

            list = new ArrayList();


            while (rs.next()) {

                nomeData = rs.getString("E3TimeStamp");
                nomeAlarme = rs.getString("Message");
                nomeRecebe = (nomeData + " " + nomeAlarme + "\n");

                list.add(nomeRecebe);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            nomeRecebe = e.getMessage();


        }
        return   String.valueOf(list);


    }

}
```

e tenho uma activit que recebe os dados

```
public class Act_Historico_Alarme extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Spinner Estacoes;
    private Button btnFechar;
    private Button btnPesquisar;
    String ESTACAO1 = "BIBLIOTECA UFV";
    String ESTACAORECEBIDA;
    Dao_Historico_Alarme DHA;
    String FalhaCon = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_historico_alarme);

        Estacoes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spn_Estacoes);
        btnFechar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFechar);
        btnFechar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPesquisar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPesquisar);
        btnPesquisar.setOnClickListener(this);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Sistema_Mobile, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        Estacoes.setAdapter(adapter);

        final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener escolha = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String item = Estacoes.getSelectedItem().toString();
                ESTACAORECEBIDA = item;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ESTACAORECEBIDA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            }


        };

        Estacoes.setOnItemSelectedListener(escolha);

    }


    private ArrayList<String> preencherDados() {

        String nomeRecebeAL1;

        DHA = new Dao_Historico_Alarme();
        nomeRecebeAL1 = DHA.nomeTabela();

        ArrayList<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>();


        dados.add(nomeRecebeAL1);


        return dados;


    }


    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnFechar) {

            finish();

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPesquisar) {

            ListView Lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List_Dados);
            ArrayList<String> Teste = preencherDados();
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Teste);
            Lista.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }}}
```

Mas ao receber os dados, ele vem no list em sequência e não quebra a linha. Como fazer esta quebra de linha?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou um "\r\n" ao invés de só "\n"? Mas pelo seu print parece que você está escrevendo um array e não uma string com as quebras

Comment: tentei mas fica na mesma

Answer (score 0):

Você está retornando o "join" do array e não a concatenação dos itens na variável `recebeNome` a qual deveria ser utilizada para receber suas mensagens de erro também. Segue o método alterado.

```
public String nomeTabela() {

        String nomeData = "";
        String nomeAlarme = "";
        String nomeRecebe = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "********";
        objConexao.db_name = "Celular";
        objConexao.db_userid = "****";
        objConexao.db_password = "******";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);

        if (conn == null) {


            nomeRecebe = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

        } else if (conn != null) try {


            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select TOP 100 Area,E3TimeStamp,Message from Alarmescelular Where AREA = ' Elevatória R7' order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
            ResultSet rs;

        rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        while (rs.next()) {
            nomeData = rs.getString("E3TimeStamp");
            nomeAlarme = rs.getString("Message");

            nomeRecebe += (nomeData + " " + nomeAlarme + '\n');               

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        nomeRecebe = e.getMessage();
    }

    return nomeRecebe;
}
```

}

Comment: da na mesma vem tudo na primeira linha

Comment: a diferença é que agora não fica separado por virgula

Answer (score 0):

olha onde estava o erro.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Teste);
```

aqui fica assim

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Teste);

obirgado